# regex returns false when should return true

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
regex = new RegExp("\${")
```

and this string:

```
path = "${wf:conf('oozie.wf.application.path')}/workflows/core"
```

When I test the string against the regexp:

```
regex .test(path)
```

it returns false, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please explain why should I use double slash? I use one to escape `$`, why second?

Let us take another example. `"\n"` is an escape-sequence in a string, producing a newline character. In order to produce the sequence `\n` (backslash, then `n`) in a string, you need to escape the backslash: `"\\n"`. To produce a regular expression that matches the string `\n` (backslash, `n`), you can't use `new RegExp("\\n")`, since that will make a new regexp of `\` and `n` (result of string escaping); but regexp again interprets `\` and `n` as newline. So you need double escape: once to tell string that you want a literal backslash, and once more to convince regexp that you want a literal backslash as well. So, to match the backslash followed by `n`, you need to do this:

```
new Regexp("\\\\n")
```

which is equivalent to

```
/\\n/
```

which will match the string in `foo` if

```
console.log(foo)
// => \n
```

In your example, it's not the backslash that is escaped, but a dollar; only regexp needs the escape on that. But you need to be sure that the backslash you escape the dollar with survives the string literal's escape mechanism:

```
"\\$"
```

will contain two characters: backslash and `$`, and regexp constructed form it will be equivalent to `/\$/`. But if you start with the string `"\$"`, it is equivalent to `"$"`, since dollars don't need escaping in regular strings; and a regexp made from that will match the end of the line, and not a dollar sign.

Answer (score 4):

You regex is equivalent to `${`. I.e. you are looking for the end of the string followed by a `{` which will never match.

Just like in regular expressions, you use `\` in string literals to escape special characters or create special escape sequences. E.g.

```
> 'foo\'bar'
"foo'bar"
```

However, if you are trying to escape a character that is not special or creating an invalid escape sequence, the backslash is just discarded:

```
> 'foob\ar'
"foobar"
```

That means, if you use a string literal to construct the regular expression, and you want to "forward" the backslash to the expression, you have to escape it as well:

```
new RegExp("\\${")
```

You can just create the expressions in the console and convince yourself:

```
> RegExp("\${")
/${/

> /${/
/${/

> RegExp("\\${")
/\${/

> /\${/
/\${/
```

---

It really is simpler to use a regex literal:

```
var regex = /\${/;
```

Comment: You still need to escape the dollar sign in the literal `/\${/`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double `\` to create `\${` as `\` is the string literal escape character.

You need a string `\${` as the regex, in string literal to represent a `\`, you need to use `\\` as a single `\` will act like a escape notation.

```
regex = new RegExp("\\${")
```

Comment: Can you please explain why should I use double slash? I use one to escape `$`, why second?

Comment: @Maximus To escape the \